# Error while inserting to Oracle DB from IIB

Tags: java, linux, oracle, ibm-integration-bus

I have a WMB application (v8) running on AIX server that makes a jdbc connection for inserting to Oracle 9 database. Now, I am migrating this to IIB(v10) running on LINUX server to update the same database. The same Insert query is throwing error in the LINUX server.

The error being shown up is:

> Error DescrptionORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

My query is:

```
INSERT INTO
EVENT_DATA(
    SEQUENCEID,
    CUSTOMERNUMBER,
    DATETIME,
    DEBTORNUMBER,
    ENDUSERID,
    PREMISENUMBER,
    REPORTEVENTID,
    REQUESTID,
    SOURCECLIENTID,
    SUCCESSINDICATOR) 
VALUES(
    73842,
    100,
    2017-09-16,
    10064393,
    Breeze1,
    303746429,
    AAMP,
    1006,
    O,
    N)
```

PS: There is nothing wrong/mismatch in column type/data as same query is executing successfully. I could not understand what is wrong with my IIB10 application running on Linux.

Comment: You really didn't use `'quotes'` around the string-literals? Or the code in your post isn't the actual code?

Comment: i am using quotes in the actual query.. i mentioned the query here just to give details on the values i am inserting

Comment: Well, I didn't really work. Try to minimalize the example, preferably to a single field, that shows the problem. It might be a string field with length above 2000 chars.

Comment: The length of string fields i am trying to insert is less than 10 chars (too less than maximum permissible size)

Comment: Try to minimalize the example, preferably to a single field, that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

The above error comes because **LONG** and **LONG RAW** datatypes have been deprecated in Oracle DB [reference](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01461_can_bind_a_long_value_only_for_insert_into_a_long_column.htm).

The solution for this could be to change your datatype from **LONG** to **CLOB**.

**Edit**:

The above error may be caused by exceeding the limit of the **varchar** or mismatch in size of varchar. try matching size of other datatypes too. i doubt the varchar size causing the above issue. due to size difference between **varchar** and **varchar2**

Comment: There is no LONG datatype i am using. All are either varchar, integer or date types.

Comment: i am using varchar2, so there is no issue with exceeding limit as you can see with the values(just few bytes). Clearly, there is no problem with the data(and its limit or type of column), because the same is being inserted successfully from other application. I feel it has something to do with Oracle Db or drivers or Operating system.